# How I do keep from updating the state before the end date is chosen in a date range with react-datepicker?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-datepicker

I have a bit of a complicated application where I'm making a chart based on the user input values. They pick a start date, and end date, and another parameter. When that extra parameter is filled, it renders the chart. The problem is when the user needs to edit the dates, in `react-datepicker`, [the start date and end date chosen are updated individually](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-date-range-for-one-datepicker), so it updates the start date and resets the end date to null before the user has chosen an end date, causing the app to error out. I need to figure out how to rework the state updating, so the user has the opportunity to pick an end date when editing the dates before the chart re-renders.

Parent component:

```
export const OutagePanel: FC<propTypes> = (props) => {
  const [parameters, setParameters] = useState({
    startDate: null,
    endDate: null,
    unit: 'None'
  })

  const handleDateChange = (range) => {
    const [startDate, endDate] = range;
    setParameters( (prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      startDate: startDate,
      endDate: endDate
    }))
  }

  const handleUnitChange = (value) => {
    setParameters( (prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      unit: value
    }))
  }

  return (
    <Flex>
      <Flex>
        <Box>Date Range:</Box>
        <Box>
          <DatePicker
            className={styles.datepicker}
            placeholderText="Click to select"
            selected={parameters.startDate}
            startDate={parameters.startDate}
            endDate={parameters.endDate} 
            onChange={handleDateChange}
            showMonthDropdown
            showYearDropdown
            dropdownMode="select"
            minDate={new Date(2000, 0, 1)}
            maxDate={new Date(2021, 0, 5)}
            todayButton="Today"
            selectsRange
          />
        </Box>
      </Flex>
      <GeneratorUnitSelect handleUnitChange={handleUnitChange} />
      {parameters.unit != 'None' && <OutageHistoryChart parameters={parameters}></OutageHistoryChart>}
    </Flex>
  )
}
```

As seen above, when `parameters.unit != 'None'` it will show the `OutageHistoryChart` component. So after it first successfully creates and displays a chart, when a user goes back to edit the dates, upon first click in the date picker, it will update the state to something like this:

```js
parameters = {
  startDate: <user's new date>,
  endDate: null,
  unit: 'Unit 1'
}
```

Since the updated state still contains a valid value in `parameters.unit` it passes my test in the return statement and tries to re-render the chart. I know I could add an additional test `parameters.endDate != null` before showing the chart and that is likely to fix it, however, it seems like I should be able to use a `useEffect` here. This is what I have tried, but the `useEffect` gets skipped upon editing the date range and it again fails to render the chart due to the end date missing.

```
export const OutagePanel: FC<propTypes> = (props) => {
  const [parameters, setParameters] = useState({
    startDate: null,
    endDate: null,
    unit: 'None'
  })

  const [showChart, setShowChart] = useState(false)
    
  const handleDateChange = (range) => {
    const [startDate, endDate] = range;
    setParameters( (prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      startDate: startDate,
      endDate: endDate
    }))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (parameters.unit != 'None' && parameters.endDate != null) {
      setShowChart(true)
    } else (
      setShowChart(false)
    )
  }, [parameters.startDate, parameters.endDate, parameters.unit])

  //more stuff
```

Then I changed it to this in the return statement:

```
{showChart && <OutageHistoryChart parameters={parameters}></OutageHistoryChart>}
```

Is this a case where a `useEffect` is not a valid solution or am I just implementing it wrong? It just seems messy to do checking like `parameter.unit != 'None' && parameter.endDate != null` in my return statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with using a `useEffect` hook to set a `showCart` state is that this leaves open at least one render cycle where `showCart` is possibly still true from a previous render and the `parameters.unit` isn't equal to `"None"` and the `parameters.endDate` *has* been updated to `null`. To guard this you're still sort of left checking `parameter !== "None"` and/or `parameter.endDate !== null` to conditionally render the `OutageHistoryChart`.

Because of this delay to update the `showCart` state you're better off computing a `showCart` value. It's considered a React anti-pattern to store derived "state" in React state anyway.

Example:

```js
const showCart = parameters.unit !== "None" && !!parameters.endDate;
```

If computing the derived state was "expensive" then you should use the `useMemo` hook to compute ***and memoize*** the result value. In fact... just about any time you find that you've coded a `useState`|`useEffect` combo to hold/update some "derived" state, you should probably be using the `useMemo` hook.

```js
const showCart = useMemo(() => {
  return parameters.unit !== "None" && !!parameters.endDate;
}, [parameters.unit, parameters.endDate]);
```

Complete code example:

```
export const OutagePanel: FC<propTypes> = (props) => {
  const [parameters, setParameters] = useState({
    startDate: null,
    endDate: null,
    unit: 'None'
  });

  const handleDateChange = (range) => {
    const [startDate, endDate] = range;
    setParameters( (prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      startDate,
      endDate
    }));
  };

  const handleUnitChange = (value) => {
    setParameters( (prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      unit: value
    }));
  };

  const showCart = parameters.unit !== "None" && !!parameters.endDate;

  return (
    <Flex>
      <Flex>
        <Box>Date Range:</Box>
        <Box>
          <DatePicker
            className={styles.datepicker}
            placeholderText="Click to select"
            selected={parameters.startDate}
            startDate={parameters.startDate}
            endDate={parameters.endDate} 
            onChange={handleDateChange}
            showMonthDropdown
            showYearDropdown
            dropdownMode="select"
            minDate={new Date(2000, 0, 1)}
            maxDate={new Date(2021, 0, 5)}
            todayButton="Today"
            selectsRange
          />
        </Box>
      </Flex>
      <GeneratorUnitSelect handleUnitChange={handleUnitChange} />
      {showCart && <OutageHistoryChart parameters={parameters} />}
    </Flex>
  );
};
```

Given the above, I think a *slightly* simpler solution would be to "reset" the `parameters.unit` state back to `"None"` if/when the `endDate` is ***going*** to be updated to `null`, or falsey, value.

```js
const handleDateChange = (range) => {
  const [startDate, endDate] = range;
  setParameters( (prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    startDate,
    endDate,
    ...!!endDate ? {} : { unit: "None" },
  }));
};
```

This allows the current condition to still work as expected.

Of course, the `parameters.unit` state should probably now also be passed to `GeneratorUnitSelect` so it's a controlled input and will "react" and show the current unit value (*there will need to be a small update to that component to accommodate*).

```
<GeneratorUnitSelect
  handleUnitChange={handleUnitChange}
  value={parameters.unit}
/>
{parameters.unit !== 'None' && <OutageHistoryChart parameters={parameters} />}
```